# Why a FORBIDDEN error is shown?

Tags: jquery, python, django

I've tried to add a drag and drop feature at the website of one of the projects I'm doing, but I get this error. It is maybe produced because of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but I have no any clue if this is the reason.

My page runs using Django, and python.

The function behind "file-upload" that is written in python seems that is not even called. How can I fix that FORBIDDEN error?

Please, ask me anything you want.

The error is shown below

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8008/file-upload 403 (FORBIDDEN) jquery.js:9631
send jquery.js:9631
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:9176
send jquery.fileupload.js:880
$.widget._onSend jquery.fileupload.js:942
(anonymous function) jqui.js:6
data.submit jquery.fileupload.js:648
(anonymous function) jquery.fileupload.js:193
fire jquery.js:3119
self.add jquery.js:3165
$.widget.options.add jquery.fileupload.js:192
e.Widget._trigger jqui.js:6
(anonymous function) jquery.fileupload.js:1008
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:383
$.widget._onAdd jquery.fileupload.js:1001
(anonymous function) jqui.js:6
(anonymous function) jquery.fileupload.js:1240
fire jquery.js:3119
self.add jquery.js:3165
promise.always jquery.js:3266
$.widget._onDrop jquery.fileupload.js:1233
(anonymous function) jqui.js:6
h jqui.js:6
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4641
elemData.handle
```

The jquery line that produce that is shown below:

```
            // Do send the request
            // This may raise an exception which is actually
            // handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
            xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );
```

My view is shown below: As I said, this function is probably not even called

```
def file_upload(request):
    # create a new plot if necessary and attach to session
    print "file upload"
    [.......]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(""),content_type="application/json")
```

also, in my urls.py:

```
urls.py:    url(r'^file-upload$', 'myproject.views.file_upload', name='file_upload'),
```

Comment: Can you show us your view code and template code? It seems that either you have to be logged in or you've forgotten to pass the CSRF token to the view.

Comment: @limelights yes, ofcourse. Give me a second

Comment: It's called but you're not sending the CSRF token.

Comment: @limelights I have posted both my python code and the code in my html file. Please see the updated question above. Hope you can help me

Comment: @limelights As far as I understand, it seems that it is sent.

Comment: What happens when you put `alert(csrftoken);` in your `$(document).ready()` function?

Comment: @limelights hmmm...it says undefined...

Comment: Have you read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax ?

Comment: @limelights, this is what I'm reading now. The application does not set an csrftoken cookie thought. I'm trying to figure that out.